# Crashed while removing the pin from mapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am working on MapView,on which I have two buttons.
1)centreButton:
   this button drops the pin annotation at the centre of the current map.
   when this button is pressed, I am storing the last annotation in a NSMutable array.
   then remove the last annotation from mapview and drop one pin at the centre of map
   Code I have done for this part is as follows:
    function for dropping the pin

```
- (void)PinDropwithlatitude:(double)lat longitude:(double)longi droptitle:(NSString *)title
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = lat;
    theCoordinate.longitude = longi;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude  = theCoordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = theCoordinate.longitude;

    //Set Zoom level using Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  =0.005;
    span.longitudeDelta =0.005;
    region.span = span;
    [MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    SetLat =lat;
    SetLong =longi;
    DDAnnotation *annotation = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
    annotation.title = title;
    annotation.subtitle = [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];
    [MapView addAnnotation:annotation];    
}
```

when I press centre button I am doing the following code and store last array in annotation.

```
-(IBAction)CenterPressed:(id)sender
 {
        //40.439631,-3.698273 -spain centre        
        [lastAnnotation addObjectsFromArray:MapView.annotations];
        NSLog(@"last annotation array=%@",lastAnnotation);
        for (id annotation in [MapView annotations]) 
        {
            if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) 
            {
                 continue;
            }
            [MapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }    
        [self PinDropwithlatitude:SetLat longitude:SetLong  
        droptitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Title", nil)];
 }
```

the log for the array is showing me the 
          last annotations you can see below::

```
       last annotation array=(
      "<+40.43963100,-3.69827300> +/- 0.00m",
        "<+40.43923187,-3.68722200> +/- 0.00m",
      "<+40.43792343,-3.67670774> +/- 0.00m",
      "<+40.43772888,-3.66711617> +/- 0.00m"
      )
```

2)UNDOButton: which removes the currently placed annotation and redrop the previous annotation, for that i have removed the annotaion from mapview, and redrop the annotation last annotation from array which i have maintained previously,using the code:

```
  -(IBAction)undoPressed:(id)sender
   {
         if ([lastAnnotation count]>0)
         {
              int countAnn = [lastAnnotation count];
              [MapView removeAnnotation:[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:countAnn-1]];  
              //[MapView delete:[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:countAnn-1]];
              [lastAnnotation removeObjectAtIndex:countAnn-1];        
              double latitude = [[[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1] annotation]coordinate].latitude;
              double longitude = [[[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1]annotation]coordinate].longitude;        
              NSLog(@"count = %d",[lastAnnotation count]);           
              [self PinDropwithlatitude:latitude longitude:longitude droptitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Title", nil)];
         }
   }
```

but when i press the undo button it crashes with the following error

**-[DDAnnotation annotation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79b8f40**

I don't get to know, where exactly the problem arises. can any one please help me to point out my mistake in the above code.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

can you try

```
[lastAnnotation  lastObject]
```

instead of

```
[[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1]
```

like

```
[MapView removeAnnotation:[lastAnnotation  lastObject]];  
[lastAnnotation removeObject:[lastAnnotation  lastObject]];
```

Comment: thanks for suggetion, i have tried this but the problem is stil persist. i think something is missing.

Comment: if [lastAnnotation count] == 1   , then you remove a annotation ,then [[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1] annotation] may get a randon value unsafe

Comment: you must ensure lastAnnotation is not empty

Comment: i am checking that at time of pressing the undobutton

Comment: if ([lastAnnotation count]>0)
 then only it allows you to remove the annotation from map

Comment: nop,  if there is only one annoation, then you remove it ,  so how could you use this code ? [[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1], there is nothing in lastAnnotation, you will fetch [lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:-1];

Comment: hmm..you are right but i have put the condition, if there is no objects in lastannotation array then it wont allow you to remove the annotaion.so there is not any question of going to get the last object from the array

Comment: double latitude = [[[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1] annotation]coordinate].latitude;
              double longitude = [[[lastAnnotation objectAtIndex:[lastAnnotation count]-1]annotation]coordinate].longitude; this is the point where i was getting crashed, so i have removed this lines. and stored the last latitude in the form of double values in array instead of storing them as an object of MKAnnotation.so, now it is working well, thanks and +1 for your support